# Где скачать Visual Basic под Windows 7?

Tags: visual-basic

Где скачать Visual Basic под Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может Visual Basic, а не виртуал?

[Скачать visual-basic-express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ru-ru/products/2010-editions/visual-basic-express)